# Another incorrect "recommend an offsite tool" close vote - does this happen often?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, recommendation-questions

I spend most of my SO time in the [f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23) tag, so I don't know if this happens elsewhere. But I often see people voting to close questions as "recommend[ing] ... an off-site resource" when the question is nothing of the kind. Latest example: [Is there any way to force Haskell code ordering to work like F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54871937/is-there-any-way-to-force-haskell-code-ordering-to-work-like-f), which as of right now has two close votes for "off-site resource" even though the question is asking "Is there a compiler option, or perhaps an IDE with some setting, to do X?" That's not asking for recommendations, which would produce opinionated answers; that's a simple question to which a factual answer exists (either there is such a compiler option or an IDE with that setting, or no such option or IDE exists). So these close votes are inappropriate.

Does this happen a lot in other, more high-traffic tags? Or is this something that happens a lot in the [f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23) tag but it doesn't happen much elsewhere, and so I'm getting a skewed view? Because from where I'm sitting at the moment, I don't see any good reason for the "recommend[s] an off-site resource" close reason to exist; I only ever see it abused, and I don't see questions where it was a good close reason. Does it get used *correctly* in other tags?

Comment: I can see why people would consider you asking for a recommendation of an IDE that has that setting, which is an off-site resource, though I've always been a little bit iffy about that close reason because some things like this likely require an external resource. The general advice I see is to just phrase your question with what you want to do (As you have in the question title and the start of the body), but by adding the suggestion that the option might be present in some compiler option or an IDE suddenly makes the question off topic...

Comment: Yep, it's about how to use the programming tools to do programming and is on topic. No recommendation here. I think people see certain keywords and close vote. It comes from a lot of browsing and less thorough reading. I do it myself at times and is something I am working on.

Comment: "Is there a tool that does X" is still asking for folks to find a tool even if you're not asking which one is the best.

Comment: It's sketchy. When it comes to IDE's there tend to be multiple options to choose from. So the question as asked really is a hidden tool recommendation with a strong opinionated attachment for answerers. The question should stick to the problem: code ordering enforcement. The line about a compiler option or IDE is pretty much fluff disguised as a trigger phrase, it should be removed.

Comment: @BSMP - Yes, that's asking people to find a tool. And what's wrong with that? Remember that the *reason* behind the close reason is "... as they tend to attract **opinionated answers** and spam" (emphasis mine). Asking "Is there a tool that does X" will not, repeat NOT, attract opinionated answers, whereas "What is the best / your favorite tool for doing X" would.

Comment: *"or perhaps an IDE with some setting"* is asking for a recommendation that is found offsite. Period. Oh, and you forgot to emphasize ***spam***. You should do that. But, hey, there's a solution to this! Edit the question to remove the product request and you've instantly salvaged the question. Tada!

Comment: What's wrong is that the close reason as written doesn't provide an exception for find/rec requests that don't attract opinionated answers and spam. It only acknowledges that not all of them will. If it's meant to be enforced that way it needs to be re-written.

Comment: They all attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow works the best if you ask how to do something, not asking for the tool you believe it would solve your issue. If you need to "force Haskell ordering", why do you need it? The ordering may have a good reason to be like that, or maybe you think that forcing the ordering would solve another issue. Without this information, is difficult to tell you the optimal solution.

The question that the user is asking is "how to prevent haskell from calling functions that hasn't been previously declared". Focus on solving that instead and edit the question so that your objective, what you are actually facing, is the problem to solve, not the problem your proposed solution introduced.

Comment: BTW, note that my answer doesn't answer your title, but the specific question you ask about. You ask if it happens often, I didn't touch that issue.